# Connecting to a DJI drone using MQTT

Tags: jquery, mqtt, dji-sdk

Part of the open source project that connects to a drone for flight planning and taking images connects to a drone using the mosquitto library using js. They tested their app using a DJI Phantom 4 Pro as indicated in the code snippet below. My question is how do I find the specific topic to include in the `client.subscribe` as a parameter in this case it was `'camera/dji.phantom.4.pro.hawk.1'`. I tried searching the dji sdk online but I cant seem to find any information. My end goal is to make the functions connect to an arbitrary drone that is SDK ready

```
// Drone Position 
    var drone_general_longtitute = 0;
    var drone_general_latitude = 0;
    var points_two = [];

    client.on('connect', function() {
        console.log('MQTT SERVER SUCCESSFULLY CONNECTED');

        jQuery('#communication_server').removeClass('offline');
        jQuery('#communication_server').addClass('online');

        client.subscribe('telemetry/dji.phantom.4.pro.hawk.1', function(err) {
            if (!err) {
                client.publish('presence', 'Hello mqtt')
            } else {
                console.log(err);
            }
        })


        client.subscribe('camera/dji.phantom.4.pro.hawk.1', function(err) {
            if (!err) {
                client.publish('presence', 'Hello mqtt')
            }
        })

        client.subscribe('missionStatus/dji.phantom.4.pro.hawk.1', function(err) {
            if (!err) {
                client.publish('presence', 'Hello mqtt')
            }
        })

        client.subscribe('missionStart/dji.phantom.4.pro.hawk.1', function(err) {
            if (!err) {
                client.publish('presence', 'Hello mqtt')
            }
        })
```

Comment: Mosquitto do not have a javascript library, I see you've tagged `mqtt.js` which  is not by mosquitto.

Answer (score 1):

You talk to the author and ask them to document what topics they are using.

You can use wildcard topic patterns to subscribe to all messages, e.g `telemetry/#` will get you all the topics that start with `telemtry/` but you will still probably need the code author to document the payload of the messages so you can make use of them.